# How to unit test a function that calls itself

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, sinon

I would like to test a recursive function that retries an input function until it is succesfull (returns true).

1. Calls a promise and awaits its fulfilment
2. If the return value is positive, stop. Else, retry while decreasing the retry count.

Here is the implementation:

```
type booleanPromiseFunc = (...args) => Promise<boolean>;

export async function retryIfFails(func: booleanPromiseFunc, retryCount: number)
{
    let result = await func();

    if (result)
        return;

    if (retryCount == 0)
        return;

    setTimeout(retryIfFails, 1000, func, retryCount - 1);
}
```

The unit test using sinon fake timers:

```
it.only('Test', function() {

    let func = sinon.stub();
    func.returns(Promise.resolve(false));

    Utils.retryIfFails(func, 2);

    chai.expect(func.callCount).eq(1);
    clock.tick(1001);
    chai.expect(func.callCount).eq(2);
    clock.tick(1001);
    chai.expect(func.callCount).eq(3);
})
```

The unit test outputs:

```
  AssertionError: expected 1 to equal 2
  + expected - actual

  -1
  +2
```

Basically, the function never calls itself.
The code in Sinon fake timers section http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock works fine. What is different about this function?

Comment: Your retryIfFails needs a promise as argument. You leave it empty at the timeout...

Answer (score 0):

When you call your function in the recursive step, you don't pass the boolean promise function as a parameter. You should do:

```
setTimeout(retryIfFails, 1000, func, retryCount - 1);
```

Also, I am not sure about how the fake timers work, but you might want to call `tick` twice with a lower value, so the timer will be triggered twice (but again, I'm not sure about this part).

Comment: Thanks, I indeed forgot to put the funtion as argument. I put it in but it still fails.